# Image resize using AWS lambda in same bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Currently i have two buckets in S3 - let's call them `buck` and `buck_thumb`. Right now, when i uploads an image in to the `buck` bucket, which triggers a lambda function that resizes the image into a thumbnail and uploads the thumbnail into the `buck_thumb` bucket.

But now i want to make it like - when i send a image url in `buck` bucket then it download the image and re size it .

Is there a way ? I can do this using only one bucket?

Answer (score 5):

What I do is I set the lambda function to SNS Message Event, so when I upload to an S3 bucket I send from my server a SNS message to the configured url, and the message is the entire path on S3 to the file, so Lambda can download it, resize it and then upload with thumb_ or whatever.

Hope it helps! This is 4 months ago, but... I hope it helps future visitors XD

Answer (score 1):

If you do it simply, then you upload -> resize -> upload -> resize..... unlimited loop.
    So, you should filter the size of the image. If the image already has been the proper size, stop the function.

```
gm(data.Body)
.size(function (err, size) {
  if(err){
    callback('gm(data.Body) error');
    context.fail(err);
  }
  if (size.width <= resizeWidth && size.height <= resizeHeight) {
    console.log('already resized')
    context.succeed({
    "error":false
     });
　  }
　});
```